# How can I convert a .jar to an .exe?

Tags: java, windows, exe

I want to convert a `.jar` to an `.exe` for microsoft. Is there any program converter for this?

Also if there's one for Mac and Linux I would appreciate suggestions for those too.

Comment: @Steve Thats on how to use GCJ (which is terrible btw), not on available options. Wrong duplicate

Comment: There is an interesting link in the answers with discussion on the topic including the software mentioned in the answers here.

Comment: I wish I could give TheLQ reputation for stating that GCJ is terrible.

Comment: Similar to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/147181/how-can-i-convert-my-java-program-to-an-exe-file). Try jpackage which is now part of JDK.

Answer (score 44):

[Launch4j](http://launch4j.sourceforge.net/) works on both Windows and Linux/Mac. But if you're running Linux/Mac, there is a way to embed your jar into a shell script that performs the autolaunch for you, so you have only one runnable file:

`exestub.sh:`

```
#!/bin/sh
MYSELF=`which "$0" 2>/dev/null`
[ $? -gt  0 -a -f "$0" ] && MYSELF="./$0"
JAVA_OPT=""
PROG_OPT=""
# Parse options to determine which ones are for Java and which ones are for the Program
while [ $# -gt 0 ] ; do
    case $1 in
        -Xm*) JAVA_OPT="$JAVA_OPT $1" ;;
        -D*)  JAVA_OPT="$JAVA_OPT $1" ;;
        *)    PROG_OPT="$PROG_OPT $1" ;;
    esac
    shift
done
exec java $JAVA_OPT -jar $MYSELF $PROG_OPT
```

Then you create your runnable file from your jar:

```
$ cat exestub.sh myrunnablejar.jar > myrunnable
$ chmod +x myrunnable
```

It works the same way launch4j works: because a jar has a [zip format](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zip_%28file_format%29), which header is located at the *end* of the file. You can have any header you want (either binary executable or, like here, shell script) and run `java -jar <myexe>`, as `<myexe>` is a valid zip/jar file.

Answer (score 16):

**JSmooth .exe wrapper**

JSmooth is a Java Executable Wrapper. It creates native Windows launchers (standard .exe) for your Java applications. It makes java deployment much smoother and user-friendly, as it is able to find any installed Java VM by itself. When no VM is available, the wrapper can automatically download and install a suitable JVM, or simply display a message or redirect the user to a website.

JSmooth provides a variety of wrappers for your java application, each of them having their own behavior: Choose your flavor!

Download: http://jsmooth.sourceforge.net/

**JarToExe 1.8**
Jar2Exe is a tool to convert jar files into exe files.
Following are the main features as describe on their website:

Can generate “Console”, “Windows GUI”, “Windows Service” three types of .exe files.

Generated .exe files can add program icons and version information.
Generated .exe files can encrypt and protect java programs, no temporary files will be generated when the program runs.

Generated .exe files provide system tray icon support.
Generated .exe files provide record system event log support.
Generated windows service .exe files are able to install/uninstall itself, and support service pause/continue.

- New release of x64 version, can create 64 bits executives. (May 18,
  2008)
- Both wizard mode and command line mode supported. (May 18, 2008)
- Download: http://www.brothersoft.com/jartoexe-75019.html

**Executor**

Package your Java application as a jar, and Executor will turn the jar into a Windows .exe file, indistinguishable from a native application. Simply double-clicking the .exe file will invoke the Java Runtime Environment and launch your application.

Comment: Do you have a link to Executor? Google is returning unrelated stuff.

Answer (score 7):

If your program is ["publicly available non-commercial in nature" and has "a publicly available Web site that meets the basic quality standards"](https://www.excelsiorjet.com/free), then you can try and get a free license of Excelsior. If its not then it's expensive, but still a viable option.

Program: https://www.excelsiorjet.com

As a side note: Here's a study of all existing Jar to EXE programs, which is a bit depressing - https://www.excelsior-usa.com/articles/java-to-exe.html

Comment: Correction: you may get a free Excelsior JET license if your project  is non-commercial and available to the general public. It does not matter if it is open source.

Comment: @Dmitry Ah thanks, habit for me to have open source = public and free.

Answer (score 5):

Despite this being against the general SO policy on these matters, this seems to be what the OP genuinely wants:

http://www.google.com/search?btnG=1&pws=0&q=java+executable+wrapper

If you'd like, you could also try creating the appropriate batch or script file containing the single line:

```
java -jar MyJar.jar
```

Or in many cases on windows just double clicking the executable jar.

Comment: Just to explain why I posted a Google link, prior to @David's edits, the OPs original question stated specifically "Please don't post telling me this is stupid or asking me why, just give me some links."

Comment: Also discussed on stackoverflow prior, here:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3754553/jar-hidden-inside-exe

Comment: You cannot add app specific icon to .bat files, and unless you use "start" the windows cmd will stay open/visible.

Answer (score 5):

I used Launch4J and it works flawlessy,

- First, Go to your jdk and copy the bin and lib folder
- Then create a folder for your app and make a folder called jre-(version),
- Then paste these inside
- Then open launch4j Put the exe file's path (Inside the app's folder)
- Then go the jre option and inside bundled paths type jre-(version)
- Then in minimun version type the version of the java you coded it in.
- Then in the jre option put "Only use private jdk runtimes"
- Then hit the gear icon. It will open a file chooser.
- Choose your application's folder, done
- Now open the exe file generated. It should work.

In case it does not, try the test run button (The green play one). If it says LinkageError in the console below, then in the jvm-options type `--enable-preview`. It should work.
I hope it helped.

Answer (score 3):

if you need to convert from `.jar` to  `.exe`  from java 14 you can used `jpackage`

> `jpackage` is a command-line tool to create native installers and
> packages for Java applications.

**Update**

`--type`
The type of package to create

`--input`
Path of the input directory that contains the files to be packaged

`--dest`
The path where generated output file is placed

`--main-jar`
The main JAR of the application containing the main class

`--main-class`
The qualified name of the application main class to execute.

`--module-path`
The path to modular jars

`--add-modules`
Add a list of modules

`--win-shortcut`
Creates a desktop shortcut for the application.

`--win-menu`
Adds the application to the system menu.

`--app-version`
A version of the application and/or package

`--verbose`
Enables verbose output

`--icon`
Path of the icon of the application package

`--jlink-options` `--bind-services`
Includes the available service providers that contain the application's main module and all of its dependencies.

Example

```
jpackage --type msi --app-version "2.0" --input . --dest . --main-jar .\JavaFXHelloWorld.jar --main-class com.example.javafxhelloworld.App --module-path "C:\Program Files\Java\javafx-jmods-17.0.1" --add-modules javafx.controls,javafx.fxml --win-shortcut --win-menu --icon "icon.ico" --name "My App" --jlink-options --bind-services
```

JPackage [documention](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/20/jpackage/packaging-overview.html#GUID-C1027043-587D-418D-8188-EF8F44A4C06A) will help you

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/30030156)

Comment: I think `jpackage` just packages your jars into a native installer (i.e. `.msi` or `.deb`, etc.) but the program still needs to be run with `java -jar ...`. I still have to test it though...

Comment: @Matthieu No you don't need to run `java -jar` you just need to run the command

Comment: @Matthieu if u using  `--jlink-options --bind-services`  u can run your `exe` or `msi` without  any java dependency in target machine

Answer (score 0):

For Windows, you can convert jar to exe using following ways:

1. Using Netbeans
   https://erainnovator.com/convert-jar-to-exe-file/
2. Using Excelsior JET
   https://youtu.be/iQSfUb8chjg

Comment: Don't post links only. Explain the basics of what they say.