# Could i convert a jar file to exe?

Tags: java

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [(Java) jar to exe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4330936/java-jar-to-exe)

What if i want to run a .jar program on a pc that doesnt have the JDK...?

would it possible?

Comment: See http://www.excelsior-usa.com/articles/java-to-exe.html

Comment: You don't need the Java Development Kit to run Java programs. You need the Java Runtime Environment.

Comment: You can run without the JRE, but you end up installing something else to provide the runtime framework. i.e. you will have to install something.

Answer (score 3):

Options include:

- Include the Java Runtime Enviroinment (JRE) in your installer. This is probably the simplest option.
- Include the JRE ''and'' Wrap your application in a small, native executable launcher. [Exe4J](http://www.ej-technologies.com/products/exe4j/overview.html) makes this easy for MS Windows.
- Compile your Java code to native executable. I haven't done this myself. A company claiming to support this is Excelsior; they have a comparison of approaches [here](http://www.excelsior-usa.com/articles/java-to-exe.html).

Answer (score 0):

If you have a site to distribute the app. from, [JWS](http://www.java.com/en/download/faq/java_webstart.xml) and [deployJava.js](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/jweb/deployment_advice.html) are a better alternative to creating an EXE.

JWS will work on any platform with Java 1.4+, and the deployJava.js will help ensure the JRE is installed.