# Execution time between jar and exe file

Tags: java

I observed that the exe converted from jar file takes considerable time in execution than original jar file. Is this correct? I used [Jar2Exe](http://www.regexlab.com/jar2exe/) to convert. Can anyone check this suggest me the best convertor?

Comment: Have you tried Excelisor JET?  I would be surprised if converting a JAR to an EXE would be much faster, I wouldn't do it for performance reasons.

Comment: why is it that you want to convert jar files to exe's? That makes a programm in a language which is designed for plattform independence depending on the platform again *confused* :-)

Comment: "Can anyone check this suggest me the best convertor?"  Best is not to convert, but to launch the software using Java Web Start (http://stackoverflow.com/tags/java-web-start/info) which works on Win, Mac & *nix.

Comment: Somewhat related : 
1. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4330936/java-jar-to-exe   

2. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4534273/could-i-convert-a-jar-file-to-exe

Comment: The platform which is using jar file needs exe format. Hence I have to give jar in exe format. Thats why I converted jar to exe with "Jar2Exe Wizard 1.8". I use java to open word files and execute some conversions. While executing with jar file it took minimum time. But when I use jar in exe format [from Jar2Exe Wizard 1.8] it took large time to open word.