# Converting to jar or exe

Tags: java

I have around 10 java files with their corresponding class files. The whole application works when i execute one of the main class. I execute it using cmd. I need help converting it into a single self executing file. eg: exe or jar

Comment: In case you are using an IDE, it should do it all for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A jar file is little more than just a zip of all classes and resource files. You need to add details into META-INF/MANIFEST.MF file so that the class containing the main method to be executed is know.

This should help: [Link](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/jar/build.html)

You can try invoking the jar file as follows:

```
java -cp <jarfile.jar> <Complete.Package.ClassNameWithMainMethod>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can make jar by Exporting the project using following methods in Eclipse IDE

File->Export->Java->JAR.

Note: This is already have a solution to change to exe or JAR.
[How can I convert a .jar to an .exe?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4330936/how-can-i-convert-a-jar-to-an-exe)