# Leiningen: Create executable jar to run without java -jar

Tags: jar, clojure, leiningen

I'm trying to understand how to package a command line application written in Clojure for distribution. I don't want users to have to use `java -jar myproject.jar arg1 arg2` to run the program. PHP has something called "Phar" files, which are basically executable zip files, so they include a shebang that tells POSIX systems how to unpack and run them.

I've seen [other Clojure apps](https://github.com/tailrecursion/boot) that allow the jar file to be set `chmod +x` and then executed directly. How do they achieve this? Uberjar just seems to make a jar that requires the `java -jar` prefix.

Comment: have you looked on the java options like http://stackoverflow.com/a/20565393/3181392 ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can do this using [lein-bin](https://github.com/Raynes/lein-bin).

Answer (score 2):

Ah, I just found the answer to my own question. It's not standard functionality and you basically have to roll your own: https://github.com/tailrecursion/boot/blob/master/Makefile#L21

Comment: Yes, i was about to answer that, they basically append the content of the jar at the the end of the bash script and launch that with java -jar. The java launcher ignores the script content and start loading the jar where it starts, really nice.