# how to create executable file for netbeans project

Tags: spring-mvc

I have a netbeans project(web application) including database connections, i want to get the executable file for my project (because i do not want to share my source code), which can run without the source code?
I have tried using jar,but extracting jar we get all the source codes.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I convert a .jar to an .exe?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4330936/how-can-i-convert-a-jar-to-an-exe)

Comment: what about doing this on a linux platform?