# How to make exe from jar using electron js

Tags: java, angular, spring-boot, electron, electron-packager

I want windows executable file (EXE) from the spring boot jar file using electron js which has UI in angular 12.

I have already made one EXE that contains only UI portion.

Comment: There is another question for converting jar to exe. It will help you. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4330936/how-can-i-convert-a-jar-to-an-exe/20565393

Comment: Yes I have one angular project and one spring boot for the rest API which is used by angular I have combined to one EXE