# How to properly make a .jar file and then convert it to .exe file so I can run it on other PCs even if they don't have Java installed on them?

Tags: java, maven, swing, jar, exe

Just like in the title. I'm having problems with it. I'm a beginner to building apps, I wrote a small program with a GUI for my work and when I converted the .jar using launch4j into .exe I can't test it because of multiple errors. I solved a few of them but I'm stuck on error like this:

```
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/mail/search/SearchTerm
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I convert a .jar to an .exe?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4330936/how-can-i-convert-a-jar-to-an-exe)

Comment: Not really. I have some kind of error there so maybe I did something wrong before using "package" in Maven?

Comment: The generated jar does not include any maven information at all.  You need to package your program with dependencies so you can run it from the command line.

Comment: @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen
Here is my pom.xml:
[link](https://pastebin.com/TkaWdDSZ)

Comment: @KamilPoniedziałek try searching the site for “runnable jar” or ask a senior colleague y

Comment: Not nearly as simple as it sounds.  Making a Jar into a executable is relatively easy with many question/answers been provided over the years, the problem is, these are all light launchers which simply launches the JVM for you (you could do the same think with a batch file, but it's nicer).  In order to launch your app, the target system MUST have a JRE installed.

Comment: What I've done in the past, is bundled a version of the JRE with a installer, this would install the app and JRE in the "Program Files" directory, create short cuts, all sorts of stuff, and configure the "exe" launcher to make use the embedded JRE.

Comment: @MadProgrammer these days Oracle want you to bring your own JRE as part of your deployment

Answer (score -1):

This helped me:
[Maven Shade Plugin](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-shade-plugin/examples/executable-jar.html)