# How to create java jar files while including external jars too?

Tags: java, command-line, jar, compilation, executable-jar

I'm creating a java app that uses external jars mainly JFreeCharts and JCommon now when I'm compiling my project with

```bash
javac -d build\classes -cp ".;build\\resources\\jfreechart-1.0.1.jar;build\\resources\\jcommon-1.0.0.jar" @files_info.txt
```

and running it with the below command while being in the build\classes directory

```bash
java -cp ".;..\\resources\\jfreechart-1.0.1.jar;..\\resources\\jcommon-1.0.0.jar" app @classes_info.txt
```

has no issues, but now I want to create a single jar file of my app so that later I can use [Launch4j to convert my jar to executable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4330936/how-can-i-convert-a-jar-to-an-exe).

Previously, when I was not using any type of external libraries I use to make jars from the below command while being in the build\classes directory

```bash
java -jar ..\app.jar
```

> Note that I'm not using my IDE for compilation or running processes I'm just using the command line in order to compile the app and make it run.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/574594/how-can-i-create-an-executable-runnable-jar-with-dependencies-using-maven/574650#574650

Comment: It is good to learn the command line tools and classpath in the beginning but when the projects become more complex, you should use a real build tool like Maven or Gradle, which already provide ready-made solutions for exactly these problems.

Comment: thanks @tgdavies to recommend me a SO question which helped me in creating jar.