# Adding Java in Pyinstaller Exe for Tabula

Tags: python, java, pyinstaller, exe, tabula

I built a python program using Tabula to read tables in pdf. I am trying to pack it into an exe and send it to others to use it, I have added the tabula jar file using --add-data. But it doesn't work because the client does not have Java installed on his laptop. I do not want him to install Java, is it possible to do it?

Comment: You need Java to run Java programs.

Answer (score 0):

You could try [Launch4j](https://launch4j.sourceforge.net/) to create an executable for tabula and embed the JRE so users don't need to download Java.

There is also [this article](https://www.baeldung.com/jar-windows-executables) that describes the steps to create and embbed Java into a Windows executable.

This SO post ['How can I convert a .jar to an .exe?'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4330936/how-can-i-convert-a-jar-to-an-exe) also gives more alternatives to that task.